# Postgresql command line variable usage in sql file

Tags: postgresql, command-line

I am using psql command to call a file bypassing argument as `-v argument=value`. In the SQL file, the argument needs to be used as part of a string. For example `prefix_:argument_suffix`. This is not working. If I use it as `prefix_:argument` it works, but when it comes to the suffix it doesn't.

This is for building a database name in the `create database` statement.

Can somebody help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another variable like:

```
nd@postgres=# \set argument 'aaa'
nd@postgres=# \set dbname 'foo_':argument'_bar'
nd@postgres=# select :'dbname';
┌─────────────┐
│  ?column?   │
├─────────────┤
│ foo_aaa_bar │
└─────────────┘

nd@postgres=# create database :dbname;
CREATE DATABASE

nd@postgres=# \l
                                    List of databases
┌─────────────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬───────────────────────┐
│    Name     │  Owner   │ Encoding │   Collate   │    Ctype    │   Access privileges   │
├─────────────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┼───────────────────────┤
│ foo_aaa_bar │ nd       │ UTF8     │ en_US.UTF-8 │ en_US.UTF-8 │                       │
│ postgres    │ postgres │ UTF8     │ en_US.UTF-8 │ en_US.UTF-8 │                       │
│ template0   │ postgres │ UTF8     │ en_US.UTF-8 │ en_US.UTF-8 │ =c/postgres          ↵│
│             │          │          │             │             │ postgres=CTc/postgres │
│ template1   │ postgres │ UTF8     │ en_US.UTF-8 │ en_US.UTF-8 │ =c/postgres          ↵│
│             │          │          │             │             │ postgres=CTc/postgres │
└─────────────┴──────────┴──────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴───────────────────────┘
```

Comment: In Oracle we have prefix_&&argument._suffix, anything similar in Postgres? I need to handle it in the statement itself.

Comment: @JeZ As I know, no. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION

Comment: In that case, let me set the parameters as you have shown. Thank you

Comment: @JeZ Yet another way is to set `prefix/suffix` variables and then use it like `create database :prefix:argument:suffix`. Choose the case most suitable for you. Good luck!

Comment: In my case, there are multiple prefixes and suffixes which are constants. So I am going with your first answer. That would suffice. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The string could be built as

```
'prefix_' || :'variable' || '_suffix'
```

To use it in a `CREATE DATABASE` statement, you will have to use dynamic SQL in a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION pg_temp.mkdb(var text) RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT AS
$$BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('CREATE DATABASE %I;', 'prefix_' || var || '_suffix');
END;$$;

SELECT pg_temp.mkdb(:'variable');
```

Since the function is created in the temporary schema, it will exist only in this database session.

Comment: This is for building a database name in the create database statement. This won't work in that case. Could you please help with that case

Comment: You should have said that in the question. See my extended answer.

Comment: Is there any possibility to do it without a function? In Oracle we have prefix_&&argument._suffix, anything similar in Postgres?